# How can I setup a php cookie so he can work for(with) iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, cookies, setcookie

I'd like to create a cookie that can "catch" a `<ifarme>`.

Here is how I imagine that;

```
<iframe id='iframe' style='display: none; border: 0; height: 0; width: 0;' src='/setcookie.php'></iframe><div> example </div>
```

Lets say that cookie expire time should be 1 day and, my question is, How that "setcookie.php" (code) should looks like or what?

I would really respect and appreciated if someone can explain/show or in any other way help me with this.

Comment: Try searching for "cookie iframe"... probably one of the 1,928 other answers will be relevant.

Comment: I tryed to, but I could not find anything fit with my issue ,unfortunatly :/ ,I will be really happy If you can help me more with this, special thanks for you! I hope you'll reply here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to set a cookie with PHP:

```
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I just copy <?php setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600); /* expire in 1 hour */ ?> and save it like "SetCookie.php" and I put it on my localhost, but it still doesnt "catch" the <iframe from the above for some reason :/ have you any other option or solution please? If not ,thanks for answer I really appreciate that. Best regards.

Comment: when you say catch the iframe what you do you mean? if you have Setcookie in setcookie.php file it will load and set the cookie from that file. You have src='/setcookie.php' make sure setcooking.php isn't labled SetCookie.php in the filename because your referencing SetCooking.php when you talk about the file.

Comment: Hello @unixmiah ,thanks for comment. Well, let me explain this little bit deeper, I want to setup(fit) a phpcookie to work with this iframe from the abov ,how? well that iframe should appear just once per visitor and when that visitor/guest reload or go anyway from site and come back that iframe should not appear ,and I find out how to include that phpcookie in to iframe with "src=cookie.php" action,but my issue now is what that "cookie.php" should include(what code exactly) to work fine and thats all. I hope you will reply me here, and thanks for reply before. Best regards for you, Aljo.